# How to compare elements of a list with elements of a map in Java?

Tags: java, list, collections

I have the following code (with some sample data), and wished to check whether there is any better or performant way to compare each element of the list of map to the subsequent one:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CompareElements {

private static List<Map<String, String>> sample = new ArrayList<>(0);
private static int MIN = 0;
private static int MAX = 10;

static {
    populateListOfMaps();
}

/*
* This is the main part of the question, rest is just to generate test data..
*/
public static void main(String[] args){
    // Can we simplify this part using lambda's or any library?
    for (int i = 0; i < sample.size() -1; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < sample.size(); j++) {
            Map<String, String> referenceMap = sample.get(i);
            Map<String, String> candideMap = sample.get(j);
            if(referenceMap.get("key").equalsIgnoreCase(candideMap.get("key"))){
                System.out.println("Equal : " + i + " || "  + referenceMap.get("key") + " and "+ j + " || " + candideMap.get("key") + " are pairs");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not equal : " + i + " || "  + referenceMap.get("key") + " and "+ j + " || " + candideMap.get("key") + " are pairs");
            }
        }
    }   
}

private static void populateListOfMaps(){
    if(sample.size() <= 10){
        Map<String, String> someMap = new HashMap<>(0);
        someMap.put("key", "value" + randInt(MIN, MAX));
        sample.add(someMap);
        populateListOfMaps();
    } 
}

public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    return randomNum;
}
```

}

My requirement is to compare each element of the list of maps and then check for equality to remove duplicate, this is a simpler part, but each map in my real time application has 2 keys-values (but both are String.. no custom POJO object).

The above code works but I wish to make this more concise and performant code.

Can we use lambdas or streams?

Comment: Any pointers. . means?

Comment: "real time" means; with a consistent latency. "real world" means; in the real world, ie. not theoretical.

Comment: "The above code works but I wish to make this more concise and performant code." - I think your question should be posted in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as it is off topic for StackOverflow

Comment: You seem to be going to great lengths to avoid POJOs which is the simplest solution. Using Maps is neither concise nor performant.

Comment: Why are your creating a HashMap with a capacity of `0` when you know the capacity needed i.e. `2`

Comment: Creating a Random each time is expensive. I would create it once and use `randInt(n)`

Comment: I implemented one way to achieve my requirement, but I am sure there might be some other interesting way. As I am still a newbie to Java8 so was wondering in case lambda's can be used for the above use-case. If yes, can somebody point me the right way (may be a sudo code, if possible). That is what I meant by "any pointers". If there is non then I think what I did works fine. Just trying to improve my knowledge. :)

Comment: @PeterLawrey you are right, I am creating random integers only to show the problem, my actual code is taking value from mongoDB. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are getting data from MongoDB, I assume you have no control over the schema, so using a POJO isn't a simple option. (it can be done with generated code, but you probably don't want to go there)

What you can do is using `groupingBy` to change this `O(n^2)` loops into `O(n)`

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    List<Map<String, String>> sample = populateListOfMaps();
    sample.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.get("key")))
            .forEach((key, list) -> System.out.println(key + " : " + list));
}

private static List<Map<String, String>> populateListOfMaps() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    return IntStream.range(0, 10)
            .mapToObj(i -> {
                Map<String, String> someMap = new HashMap<>(2);
                someMap.put("key", "value-" + rand.nextInt(10));
                return someMap;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This will print all the entries which have the same "key" value with `O(n)` time complexity. e.g.

```
value-9 : [{key=value-9}]
value-8 : [{key=value-8}, {key=value-8}, {key=value-8}]
value-5 : [{key=value-5}]
value-7 : [{key=value-7}, {key=value-7}]
value-1 : [{key=value-1}]
value-0 : [{key=value-0}]
value-2 : [{key=value-2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not realy sure what your exact requirements are so to tackle your question one part at a time:

> check whether there is any better or performant way to compare each element of the list of map to the subsequent one:

How about using keySets?

```
Set<String> s1 = new HashSet< String >(referenceMap.values());
Set<String> s2 = new HashSet< String >(candideMap.values());

// Get intersection of values
s1.retainAll(s2);

// You can also get corresponding keys for each value later
```

This should reduce your complexity from `O(n^2)` to `O(n)`

> each map in my real time application has 2 keys-values (but both are String.. no custom POJO object).

Not sure what you mean by real-time. Are the maps changing in real time? Neither your solution nor mine would be thread safe.

Do you mean 2 keys-values for each entry? If you mean 2 values for each key, you would probably override the `hashcode()`, `equals()` and your code should work.

Let me know if I misunderstood your question